# Implement large median filter with OpenCL

Tags: filter, opencl, median, quantile

In an algorithm we are using a median filter with a big window of 257x257 on a UInt16 image. My task is to implement that algorithm with OpenCL on a GPU.

In fact I do not only need the median but in some cases also the 0.001, 0.02 and 0.999 quantiles.

The obvious approach is to have a OpenCL kernel running on every output pixel where the kernel loads all pixels in the window form the input image to local memory, then sorts these values and finally computes the quantiles.

Now the problem is with a window size of 257x257 this approach would need at least 132098 bytes of local memory. But local memory is very limited. My Quadro K4000 has only 49152 bytes.

So what would be a good approach to implement such a median filter on the GPU?

A solution for CUDA would also be acceptable. But I guess the underlying problem would be the same.

Comment: @talonmies This question is about how to implement a large median filter on a GPU where local memory is very limited. I don't think this is a very broad question. So I don't agree with the downvote. I don't agree with your removal of the CUDA tag either. This question is related to CUDA as much as it is related to OpenCL. The limitation comes from the hardware and a possible solution for working around this limitation would most probably look very similar no matter if I use OpenCL or CUDA. I'm trying to solve a problem using CUDA (or OpenCL), so this question _is_ related to CUDA.

Comment: CUDA and OpenCL are not the same even on NVIDIA hardware. Either ask a question about OpenCL or CUDA. But not both.

Comment: You could simply replace the usage of local/shared memory with private memory. Of course 257*257 uint16 values for each thread is (most likely) more than your card can provide. However, to my knowledge, OpenCL implementations will transparently use global instead of private memory if not enough private memory can be provided. You as a user should only notice this performance wise since global memory is much slower than private (or local) memory. Can anyone confirm my thoughts, maybe @talonmies ?

Comment: There is no explanation of *why* you think you need all that shared memory to implement a median filter. Google for "median of medians" - this is a solved problem.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I've already had a look at the _median of medians_ algorithm. If I understand it correctly, it will rearrange the input values in the window. Since the windows for all the output pixels overlap, I will still need a local copy of the input window in every thread. Or am I wrong?

Comment: At the moment the only possible solution I see is to build a histogram (with 1000 bins or so) and then compute the approximate quantiles based on this histogram.

Comment: You don't need to reorder the source data to implement a median-of-medians style calculation. Just store the medians in shared/local memory buffer and extract the median after pushing 237 individual row or column medians. If you are clever, you can even perform a "rolling" window where each block/work group processes a whole image row or column, in which case you only need to remove and add the median of a single window row per input data point.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! This was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Two general tips:

1. Nested radix sort
2. Reusing datastructures for neighbouring pixels

Radix sort works well, because [image: 257^2 > 2^{16}] and therefore several bins will be reused. But you can save more memory by nesting it. Imagine one histogram for the values divided by 256, then you know which bin the median is in and any of the other percentiles. Then you go over the values a second time and accumulate the residue to dial in on the the exact value.

The histograms can be reused for neighbouring pixels, because the 257×257 boxes overlap strongly. For each neighbour, you only need to remove the 257 pixels that are not in the new box any more and add the new 257 pixels that replace them. So I'd suggest workgroups as large as possible whil still utilizing all of the parallelism the GPU offers, somewhere between 16×1 to 256×1.